# How to plot adjacency matrix using .csv file with row headers and column headers in Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have a csv file with data as below

|  | ANXIETY | HEADACHE | INSOMNIA | NAUSEA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HEADACHE | 20 | 14 |  | 2 |
| INSOMNIA | 11 |  |  |  |
| NAUSEA | 3 | 7 | 6 | 3 |
| ANXIETY | 11 |  | 5 |  |

I eventually want to plot an adjacency matrix using Networkx so I used the below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import genfromtxt
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('D:\\DistanceMatix.csv',sep=',',header=0,index_col=[0])
```

but when I tried as below to print the adjacency it gave an error

```
adjacency = df[1:,1:]
print(adjacency)
```

I also tried using
`np.genfromtxt('D:\\DistanceMatix.csv', delimiter= ',',skip_header=1)` 
but then the issue is it is showing Nan for row headers and column headers. How can I get row and column headers and use them as nodes to create edges in Networkx

Comment: Can you provide the exact content of the csv file (as text, not as table)?

Comment: @mozway -  below is the content of the csv file 


,ANXIETY,HEADACHE,INSOMNIA,NAUSEA
HEADACHE,20,14,,2
INSOMNIA,11,,,,  
NAUSEA,3,7,6,3
ANXIETY,11,,5,